# Destroying Polymer-element and re-create new one with other attributes...or?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0, pubnub

I'm wondering what's the best approach to do the following: I have a `Polymer-element` (`PubNub` (which handled `Realtime Messaging`)) which is "instantiated" with a some attribute values (the elements properties (more precisely, which channel to listen to/join)). And since the user should be able to switch chat rooms (/channels), I'm not sure if it's such a great idea to "instantiate" 5 `PubNub-elements` and in turn have 5 active chats going on in the background (receiving messages), if nothing else it would drain more battery power(?).

So, should I instantiate one `PubNub-element` and then remove and replace it when a user swaps channel? And how is this done best in `Polymer`?

Or is there some other approach one should take when dealing with this kind of problem?

Comment: You should only have one PubNub-element (instance) and move in and out of the 5 different chats (channels). I will have our PubNub Polymer engineer review this and provide a formal answer for you.

Comment: Thank you Craig, I look forward to an answer! At the moment I've modified the PubNub-Polymer-element itself since it lacks a lot of functionality.

Comment: It needs to be updated to latest version, too. Feel free to share you updates on the github repo as a PR.

Comment: My changes are very untested and not very "thought through", they are simply made to work so that I can test my concept, nothing more. Also, there is a pull-request already updating a lot of stuff in the pubnub-element that should be pulled and merged. Hope you get time to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the current pubnub-element is very basic and lacks many functionalities, as you have already noticed.

As Craig said, I don't generally recommend to create a bunch of instances either, however, the polymer element lacks the way you can modify all properties on the fly- you may be able to change the channel name as publishing, but it doesn't work the way for subscribing...

Instead of making some workaround using Polymer elements, I suggest to just use our vanilla JavaScript APIs. It maybe so much easier for your scenario.

And please do not hesitate to send us a pull requests or two :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment I've implemented functionality to re-subscribe (run the `sub`-method) to a new channel when `channel`-property changes and it seems to work. But I'm considering using channel-groups instead and listen to all channels in that group and just filter the messages, or is this only recommended in private-chat channels?